# Are there any malware for USB-connected printers

Tags: malware

At work, we have a printer/scanner that connects only to USB. As far as I know, no one who uses it has a print server on their computers so I'm not sure it's accessible over the internet. Because most of the other employees have a habit of downloading files illegally, there's a good chance most of the computers that have connected to this printer have some sort of infection. One employee even complained of problems during shutdown/reboot.

I've tried researching on the kinds of infections affecting printers and have mostly only found articles describing networked printers.

Is it possible to infect a USB-connected printer in a way that would infect computers connected to it?

Since the printer will inevitably have to be used at some point, if this were the case, is there a way to safely plug it into my computer and use it?